# How I can use logarithms in C language

Tags: c, math, logarithm

I want to execute logx in C, but I found out that the math library in C, only provides logs with bases e and 10. How is it possible to get a logarithm in some other basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change%5Fof%5Fbase

> The logarithm `log_b(x)` can be computed from the logarithms of `x` and `b` with respect to an arbitrary base `k` using the following formula:
>
> `log_b(x) = ln(x) / ln(b)`